# I can't get my game of life program to work because of wrap around

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

I have a few methods that should run the conway's game of life but in my neighbor count method I don't know how to account for wrap around. I'll put the methods that do this up.
Again I mostly just need help with my neighborCount method. I have tested the other methods and they seem to work just fine but when I test the problem method it returns really bogus values.

```
public class GameOfLife {

private boolean[][] society;
private boolean cell = true;
private boolean empty = false;

public GameOfLife(int rows, int cols) {
    // Complete this method.
    society = new boolean[rows][cols];
    for (int r = 0; r < society.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < society[0].length; c++) {
            society[r][c] = empty;
        }
    }
}
public void growCellAt(int row, int col) {
    // Complete this method
    society[row][col] = cell;
}
public int neighborCount(int row, int col) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int r = 0; r < society.length; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < society[0].length; c++) {
            // up and left
            if (society[(r - 1 + row) % row][(c - 1 + col) % col] == cell) {
                count++;
            }
            // up
            if (society[(r - 1 + row) % row][c] == cell) {
                count++;
            }
            // up and right
            if (society[(r - 1 + row) % row][(c + 1 + col) % col] == cell) {
                count++;
            }
            // right
            if (society[r][(c + 1 + col) % col] == cell) {
                count++;
            }
            // down and right
            if (society[(r + 1 + row) % row][(c + 1 + col) % col] == cell) {
                count++;
            }
            // down
            if (society[(r + 1 + row) % row][c]){
                count++;
            }
            // down and left
            if (society[(r + 1 + row) % row][(c - 1 + col) % col] == cell) {
                count++;
            }
            // left
            if (society[r][(c - 1 + col) % col] == cell) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do with `(r - 1 + row) % row`?  Why are you subtracting 1?  Are you 1-indexing your cells or something?  And are `row` and `col` values passed to the `neighborCount()` function the coordinates of the cell you're checking or the dimensions of the "board"?  Because if they're the former, the logic looks certainly wrong.

Comment: im trying to see if the 8 spaces around my location have a cell in them. I'm trying to account for out of bound exceptions. In this case row and col are the cell im checking.

Comment: The more important part of that question was what are `row` and `col` -- see @paddy's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your modulo looks to be using the wrong values.  ALthough, it's hard to tell because the logic inside that function is a bit odd.

If `row` and `col` are indices of the cell you want to test (as they seem to be elsewhere), then it's definitely wrong.  You need to mod by the actual row length and column length.  *ie*

```
society[(r - 1 + row) % society.length][(c - 1 + col) % society[0].length]
```

Beware that modulo of a negative number is generally not a good idea.  I don't know if this applies in java or not, but the normal approach is to avoid them.  To get around that:

```
(r + society.length - 1 + row) % society.length
(c + society[0].length - 1 + col) % society[0].length
```

Comment: neither of those really worked out for me. the max it can return is 8 and I kept getting values like 24.

Comment: That's because you're looping over the entire grid and counting everything.  Like I said, your logic was odd.  If that's meant to count only the immediate neighbours, then remove the loops.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using something simpler, like this:

```
public Cell[] getNeighbours(int i, int j) {
int i2 = i - 1, i3 = i + 1, j2 = j - 1, j3 = j + 1;
if (i2 == -1) i2 = board.length - 1;
if (i3 == (board.length)) i3 = 0;
if (j2 == -1) j2 = board[i].length - 1;
if (j3 == (board[i].length)) j3 = 0;
return new Cell[]{board[i2][j2], board[i2][j], board[i2][j3], board[i][j2], board[i][j3], board[i3][j2], board[i3][j], board[i3][j3]};
```

}